# Can I highlight area borders with Google Maps API 3?

Tags: google-maps, highlight, country

Let's start with an example:  if I search for Alaska in maps.google.com it gives a map of Alaska with red borders.

**How can I get similar results with Google Maps Api 3?**

I understand that it is possible with overlays and KML data, but "the google way" would be better and more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to do this in the Maps API. You would have to do it with an overlay.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the confirmation. Though, it means more work. At least this API is more than enough while considering possibilities such as overlay.